# How to call nested object variable correctly in the cd -path?

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell under win10-64 bits. I am entering a path in the -path argument under the "Set-location" function. My path variable is a property from a System.Array, which is "$list.name".  In a loop, I recurrently call ".\$list.name[$i]" to be the path, but I failed. I want to correctly call the nested variable.

1. the code to show variable

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Rainmeter\Skins> $list
label name   link                                                        sort
----- ----   ----                                                        ----
    1 chrome C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe    1
    1 matlab C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\matlab.exe                  3

PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Rainmeter\Skins> $i=0
```

2. the code to show the error

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Rainmeter\Skins> Set-Location -Path .\$list.name[$i]
Set-Location : could not find path “.\ .name[0]”，the path is not existed.
+ Set-Location -Path .\$list.name[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\ .name[0]:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

1. I have tried to add double quote,it failed.As below,

```
Set-Location -Path ".\$list.name[$i]"
```

2. I have to name another variable to substitute the nested variable. It works, but not beautiful. As below,

```
$file = $list.name[$i]
Set-Location -Path $file
```

I want to correctly call the nested variable in -path parameter under the loop and know the reason for the error.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a [subexpression operator (`$(...)`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators). PowerShell will execute within the brackets *before* substituting the string. e.g.:

```
Set-Location -Path ".\$($list.name[$i])"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the location to a file, use `Split-Path` to get the parent of the link, not the name.

```
Set-Location -Path (Split-Path -Path $list.link[$i] -Parent)
```